# Is this usage of "advocate" correct?

Tags: word-usage

https://engoo.com/app/daily-news/article/burnout-rising-among-women-in-the-workplace/xQsQoC1UEey55SOTigiluQ

> > "Planned Parenthood" is a non-profit organization that advocates for women's reproductive rights.

It says "advocates for women's reproductive rights" but I wonder why there is "for" here though to advocate is a transitive verb.  Do you need "for" here?  Or is this just a typo?

Comment: Which dictionary did you consult?  How do you know it is a transitive verb?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.  For example, [Wiktionary, sense 3](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advocate#Verb)

> 3. (intransitive, with for) To engage in advocacy.

or Cambridge, with [ T ] meaning transitive and [ I ] meaning intransitive:

> verb [ I/T ]
>
> to speak in support of an idea or course of action:
> [ T ] Some people advocate teaching to the test.
> [ I ] The organization advocates for human rights.

It is possible that some learners' dictionaries don't have the full range of this word's use.